# How to create folder and file in SharePoint at the same time using REST API

Tags: rest, folder, file, sharepoint-rest-api

Using REST API, is there a way we can upload a file to SharePoint and also create the folder to which file to be uploaded. Say for example here **“/testfolder”** does not exist already in SharePoint and we need to create the folder at the time of uploading the file.

```
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(@folderurl)/Files/add(url=@filename)?@folderurl='/sites/sitename/foldername/testfolder'&@filename='sn_test_01.txt'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible via REST API....Infact it is one of limitation that for doing some simple things you need to make multiple calls in REST API.

To create folder you need to make below call

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/folders
method: POST
body: { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl': '/document library relative url/folder name'}
Headers: 
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    X-RequestDigest: form digest value
    accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-type: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-length:length of post body
```