# Will SharePoint automatically create intermediary folders when adding a file through the REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, file-upload, folder

I have read this [question and answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203233/how-to-create-folder-and-file-in-sharepoint-at-the-same-time-using-rest-api), but the REST call in that question is attempting to grab a folder by `GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl` and then add a file directly to it, so clearly if the folder is not already there, you won't be able to get it.

But what if I constructed a URL like this:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('My Library')/rootfolder/files/add(url='folder1/folder2/filename.docx')
```

Would SharePoint create `folder1` and `folder2` on the way to adding the file?

Or, what about if, as in the answer linked to, I had to make a separate call to create the folder, but when creating the folder I actually want to create several nested folders.  So again, imagine that there's only the root folder of the document library, and I did

```
{
    '__metadata': {
        'type': 'SP.Folder'
    },
    'ServerRelativeUrl': '/sites/MySite/MyDocLib/folder1/folder2/folder3'
}
```

Would SharePoint automatically create all three subfolders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would SharePoint automatically create all three subfolders?

As per my analysis SharePoint REST API will not create all three subfolders automatically.

If `folder1` is not exist in the document library then it will throw **Not Found** error.

Below is a code I am using for creating folders in document library:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createFolder(folderPath, newFolderName) {
        var folderEndpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('" + folderPath + "')/folders/add(url=\'" + newFolderName + "\')";

        $.ajax({
            url: folderEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Folder created successfully");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**OR**:

```
function createFolderWithPayload() {
        var folderEndpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/folders";
        var folderPayload = {
            "__metadata": {
                "type": "SP.Folder"
            },
            "ServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/SiteName/Shared Documents/folder1"
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: folderEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(folderPayload),
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Folder created successfully");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

Considering I have only a document library and there is no folder in it.

**Scenario 1**:

When I tried:

```
createFolder('/sites/SiteName/Shared Documents', 'folder1')
```

It will create a `folder1` as it does not exist in document library.

**Scenario 2**:

When I tried:

```
createFolder('/sites/SiteName/Shared Documents/folder2', 'folder3')
```

Throws an error that `folder2` not found.

> Would SharePoint create folder1 and folder2 on the way to adding the file?

**Above scenario's are same with adding file.**

Below is a code I am using for creating files in document library:

```
function createFile(folderPath, newFileName) {
        var fileEndpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('" + folderPath + "')/Files/add(url=\'" + newFileName + "\',overwrite=true)";

        $.ajax({
            url: fileEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Folder created successfully");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

Considering I have only a document library and there is no folder in it.

**Scenario 1**:

When I tried:

```
createFile('/sites/SiteName/Shared Documents', 'rest.txt')
```

It will create a `rest.txt` as it does not exist in document library.

**Scenario 2**:

When I tried:

```
createFile('/sites/SiteName/Shared Documents/folder1', 'rest.txt')
```

Throws an error that **File not found**.

**Microsoft Documentation**: [Working with folders and files with REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest)